# US Election Twitter Data

Tags: usa, api, elections

Is there a way that I can get US election-related tweets from October 15 to Nov 15 from various countries.

Can anyone tell how to use the Twitter API to get data older than a month? Alternatively, does any one know of sources where I can get this data which includes tweet content, location, date, time etc.? Any sort of help much appreciated.

Comment: You can get old twitter content with the API if you know the tweet or user ID. Otherwise, you can search up to ~7 days previous.

Answer (score 1):

Some researchers have published:

[2016 United States Presidential Election Tweet Ids dataset](https://gwu-libraries.github.io/sfm-ui/posts/2016-11-30-election-dataset)

> ... the SFM team is sharing the tweet id of every single tweet that we collected around the election – all 280 million of them. The tweets are broken up into 12 collections:
>
> Candidates and key election hashtags (Twitter filter)
>
> Democratic candidates (Twitter user timeline)
>
> Democratic Convention (Twitter filter)
>
> Democratic Party (Twitter user timeline)
>
> Election Day (Twitter filter)
>
> First presidential debate (Twitter filter)
>
> GOP Convention (Twitter filter)
>
> Republican candidates (Twitter user timeline)
>
> Republican Party (Twitter user timeline)
>
> Second presidential debate (Twitter filter)
>
> Third presidential debate (Twitter filter)
>
> Vice Presidential debate (Twitter filter)

[Link to data](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi%3A10.7910%2FDVN%2FPDI7IN)

---

Twitter's [terms of service](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/compliance/overview) state that you can't share the tweet content, and only the tweet id. This is to allow users to delete the content, and keep the [right to be forgotten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_be_forgotten).

When you have a list of tweet ids, you can retrieve the tweet content, assuming it hasn't been deleted.

The Twitter API endpoint to retrieve a tweet based on its id is here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-show-id.html

or up to 100 tweet ids at a time: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-lookup

---

There are tons of programming libraries to access the API - pick your favorite (Python, R, etc) and search for the best.